# Postgres unique constraint not enforcing uniqueness

Tags: postgresql

Here is my constraint:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_subscriptions_on_user_id_and_class_type_id_and_deleted_at
  ON subscriptions
  USING btree
  (user_id, class_type_id, deleted_at);
```

This query proves the constraint is not actually working:

```
SELECT id, user_id, class_type_id,deleted_at
FROM subscriptions;
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Why is uniqueness not being enforced?

Comment: You might be interested by this answer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9759/postgresql-multi-column-unique-constraint-and-null-values/18110#18110

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Unique indexes in Postgres are based on values being *equal*, but NULL is never equal to anything, including other NULLs. Therefore any row with a NULL deleted_at value is distinct from any other possible row - so you can insert any number of them.

One way around this is to create *partial indexes*, applying different rules to rows with and without NULLs:

```
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ... ON subscriptions
 (user_id, class_type_id) WHERE deleted_at IS NULL;

 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ... ON subscriptions
 (user_id, class_type_id, deleted_at) WHERE deleted_at IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 9):

This happens because of the `NULL` value in the `created_at` column. A unique index (or constraint) allows multiple rows with `NULL` in them.

The only way you can prevent that is to either declare the column as `NOT NULL` in order to force a value for it, or reduce the unique columns to `(user_id, class_type_id)`