# Postgres unique constraint vs index

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, unique

As I can understand [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-unique.html) the following definitions are equivalent:

```
create table foo (
    id serial primary key,
    code integer,
    label text,
    constraint foo_uq unique (code, label));

create table foo (
    id serial primary key,
    code integer,
    label text);
create unique index foo_idx on foo using btree (code, label);
```

However, a note in [the manual for Postgres 9.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/indexes-unique.html) says:

> The preferred way to add a unique constraint to a table is `ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT`. The use of indexes to enforce unique constraints
>   could be considered an implementation detail that should not be
>   accessed directly.

(Edit: this note was removed from the manual with Postgres 9.5.)

Is it only a matter of good style? What are practical consequences of choice one of these variants (e.g. in performance)?

Comment: The (only) practical difference is that you can create a foreign key to a unique constraint but not to a unique index.

Comment: An advantage the other way around ([as came up in another question recently](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23449309/157957)) is that you can have a *partial* unique index, such as "Unique ( foo ) Where bar Is Null". AFAIK, there's no way to do that with a constraint.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm not sure when this happened, but this no longer appears to be true.  This SQL fiddle allows foreign key references to a unique index:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/20ee9;   EDIT:  adding a 'filter' to the unique index causes this to stop working (as expected)

Comment: from postgres documentation: PostgreSQL automatically creates a unique index when a unique constraint or primary key is defined for a table. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-unique.html

Comment: I concur with @user1935361, if it were not possible to create a foreign key to a unique index (with PG 10 at least) I would have run into this issue a long time ago.

Comment: [postgres mailing list answer](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAO8h7BJMX5V1TqzScTx2Nr1jH5iUFG8A071y-g1b_kdzpu9PDw%40mail.gmail.com)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I was under the same impression (fk requires unique *constraint*), but that seems to have been a misunderstanding all along. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61249732/939860

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Another difference is that [you cannot use the `ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT` clause with unique indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62322630/521799)

Comment: one of the differences is deferrable behavior - constraints support it, indexes don't https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html

Comment: @maggu Yes, when I add 'id serial primary key' to my CREATE TABLE... DDL, it looks like postgresql automatically adds a CREATE UNIQUE INDEX source DDL

Comment: @nameless_horse what do you mean with your poor comment?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

I had some doubts about this basic but important issue, so I decided to learn by example.

Let's create test table *master* with two columns, *con_id* with unique constraint and *ind_id* indexed by unique index.

```
create table master (
    con_id integer unique,
    ind_id integer
);
create unique index master_unique_idx on master (ind_id);

    Table "public.master"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers
--------+---------+-----------
 con_id | integer |
 ind_id | integer |
Indexes:
    "master_con_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (con_id)
    "master_unique_idx" UNIQUE, btree (ind_id)
```

In table description (\d in psql) you can tell unique constraint from unique index.

**Uniqueness**

Let's check uniqueness, just in case.

```
test=# insert into master values (0, 0);
INSERT 0 1
test=# insert into master values (0, 1);
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "master_con_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (con_id)=(0) already exists.
test=# insert into master values (1, 0);
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "master_unique_idx"
DETAIL:  Key (ind_id)=(0) already exists.
test=#
```

It works as expected!

**Foreign keys**

Now we'll define *detail* table with two foreign keys referencing to our two columns in *master*.

```
create table detail (
    con_id integer,
    ind_id integer,
    constraint detail_fk1 foreign key (con_id) references master(con_id),
    constraint detail_fk2 foreign key (ind_id) references master(ind_id)
);

    Table "public.detail"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers
--------+---------+-----------
 con_id | integer |
 ind_id | integer |
Foreign-key constraints:
    "detail_fk1" FOREIGN KEY (con_id) REFERENCES master(con_id)
    "detail_fk2" FOREIGN KEY (ind_id) REFERENCES master(ind_id)
```

Well, no errors. Let's make sure it works.

```
test=# insert into detail values (0, 0);
INSERT 0 1
test=# insert into detail values (1, 0);
ERROR:  insert or update on table "detail" violates foreign key constraint "detail_fk1"
DETAIL:  Key (con_id)=(1) is not present in table "master".
test=# insert into detail values (0, 1);
ERROR:  insert or update on table "detail" violates foreign key constraint "detail_fk2"
DETAIL:  Key (ind_id)=(1) is not present in table "master".
test=#
```

Both columns can be referenced in foreign keys.

**Constraint using index**

You can add table constraint using existing unique index.

```
alter table master add constraint master_ind_id_key unique using index master_unique_idx;

    Table "public.master"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers
--------+---------+-----------
 con_id | integer |
 ind_id | integer |
Indexes:
    "master_con_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (con_id)
    "master_ind_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (ind_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "detail" CONSTRAINT "detail_fk1" FOREIGN KEY (con_id) REFERENCES master(con_id)
    TABLE "detail" CONSTRAINT "detail_fk2" FOREIGN KEY (ind_id) REFERENCES master(ind_id)
```

Now there is no difference between column constraints description.

**Partial indexes**

In table constraint declaration you cannot create partial indexes. 
It comes directly from the [definition](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html) of `create table ...`. 
In unique index declaration you can set `WHERE clause` to create partial index. 
You can also [create index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html) on expression (not only on column) and define some other parameters (collation, sort order, NULLs placement).

You **cannot** add table constraint using partial index.

```
alter table master add column part_id integer;
create unique index master_partial_idx on master (part_id) where part_id is not null;

alter table master add constraint master_part_id_key unique using index master_partial_idx;
ERROR:  "master_partial_idx" is a partial index
LINE 1: alter table master add constraint master_part_id_key unique ...
                               ^
DETAIL:  Cannot create a primary key or unique constraint using such an index.
```

Comment: is it actual info? especially about partial indexes

Comment: @anatol - yes, it is.

Comment: @klin About the last part, [you can't add a custom-sorted index as constraint either](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77476513/5298879)

Answer (score 49):

One more advantage of using `UNIQUE INDEX` vs. `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` is that you can easily `DROP`/`CREATE` an index [`CONCURRENTLY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY), whereas with a constraint you can't.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible to drop concurrently a unique index. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-dropindex.html "There are several caveats to be aware of when using this option. Only one index name can be specified, and the CASCADE option is not supported. (Thus, an index that supports a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint cannot be dropped this way.)"

Comment: In Postgres 12.0 I receive no error when attempting to drop a unique index concurrently; the table definition after running the command shows that the index was indeed dropped.

`DROP INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF EXISTS idx_name`

Answer (score 33):

> Uniqueness is a constraint.  It happens to be implemented via the creation
>   of a unique index since an index is quickly able to search all existing
>   values in order to determine if a given value already exists.
>
> Conceptually the index is an implementation detail and uniqueness should be
>   associated only with constraints.

[The full text](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAO8h7BJMX5V1TqzScTx2Nr1jH5iUFG8A071y-g1b_kdzpu9PDw%40mail.gmail.com)

So speed performance should be same

Comment: From that quote I read the speed performance is faster in index and NOT the same. I thought that is the whole reason for index.

Comment: @Zaffer: Probably you confused by `quickly`, it is not equal `quicker`. Quote says that index is used to check that value already exists. And this task is done quickly. Also it says that when you use `unique constraint` under hood it uses `index`. Because of that performance is same.

Answer (score 21):

Since various people have provided advantages of unique indexes over unique constraints, here's a drawback: a unique constraint can be deferred (only checked at the end of the transaction), a unique index can not be.

Comment: How can this be, given that all unique constraints have a unique index?

Comment: Because indexes do not have an API for deferring, only constraints do, so while the deferral machinery exists under the cover to support unique constraints, there's no way to declare an index as deferrable, or to defer it.

Comment: Interesting observation. So when using constraints (vs indexes) one can have conflicting data during transaction but if it’s fine at the end, then it would succeed? Indexes would fail earlier as I understood.

Comment: That is correct, assuming the constraint is deferrable and deferred. Also note that not all constraints are deferrable: `NOT NULL` and `CHECK` constraints are always immediate.

Comment: @Masklinn does user need to do anything to make them deferrable/deferred? Speaking about uniqueness constraints. UPD: found this https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/deferring-database-constraints

Comment: You need to create the constraint as `DEFERRABLE` in the first place (the default is `NOT DEFERRABLE`), and either create it as `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` (in which case it's always deferred by default), or `SET CONSTRAINTS <constraint_name> DEFERRED` in the specific transactions where you want to defer the constraint's checking. Which is best depends on your specific use case e.g. whether you always want the constraint to be deferred, or only have a few places where that's a necessity.

Answer (score 17):

A very minor thing that can be done with constraints only and not with indexes is using the `ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT` clause ([see also this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62292586/521799)).

This doesn't work:

```sql
CREATE TABLE T (a INT PRIMARY KEY, b INT, c INT);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX u ON t(b);

INSERT INTO T (a, b, c)
VALUES (1, 2, 3)
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT u
DO UPDATE SET c = 4
RETURNING *;
```

It produces:

```
[42704]: ERROR: constraint "u" for table "t" does not exist
```

Turn the index into a constraint:

```sql
DROP INDEX u;
ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT u UNIQUE (b);
```

And the `INSERT` statement now works.

Comment: But on unique index you can still do by listing fields in braces: ON CONFLICT (b) DO UPDATE SET

Answer (score 16):

Another thing I've encountered is that you can use sql expressions in unique indexes but not in constraints.

So, this does not work:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    name text,
    UNIQUE (lower(name))
);
```

but following works.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    name text
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uq_name on users (lower(name));
```

Comment: I would use the `citext` extension.

Comment: @ceving it depends on the use case. sometimes you want to preserve casing while ensuring case-insensitive uniqueness

Comment: I ran into this as well. I was worried that not being able to add the constraint would be a problem but it seems to be working fine.   I tried to do: ALTER TABLE films ADD CONSTRAINT unique_file_title UNIQUE USING INDEX lower_title_idx; but got error Cannot create a primary key or unique constraint using such an index. Index contains expressions. I tried inserting case-insensitive data and it seems to work even without the constraint.

Comment: I needed this specific functionality too, and I could achieve it using function indices as described, while constraints didn't help.

Answer (score 7):

There is a difference in locking.
Adding an index does not block read access to the table.
Adding a constraint does put a table lock (so all selects are blocked) since it is added via **ALTER TABLE**.

Comment: this is a good point I think

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, there's a topic of whether unique constraints are also used to speed-up queries as indexes are.

Apparently constraints are actually used for Index Scans as indicated by EXPLAIN:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
    ADD CONSTRAINT mytable_uc UNIQUE (other_id, name);

explain select * from mytable
    where name = 'name' and other_id = 154
```

Result:

```
Index Scan using mytable_uc on mytable  (cost=0.28..2.29 rows=1 width=101)
  Index Cond: ((other_id = 154) AND ((name)::text = 'name'::text))
```

Answer (score 1):

As of PostgreSQL 16.1, both still end up [enforcing uniqueness](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index-unique-checks.html) exactly the same way but aren't equivalent in terms of how they command the underlying index. There's also a third way to do `unique`, in the form of [exclusion constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE) (since 9.0, but below matrix refers to state as of 16.1):

| control over | index | constraint | index as constraint | exclusion constraint |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [collation, direction, `null` order](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#id-1.9.3.69.6) | YES | no | [no](https://dbfiddle.uk/7iqUNzfV) | YES |
| [custom equality](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createoperator.html) | no | no | no | YES |
| [`include`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#id-1.9.3.69.6) payload column | YES | YES | YES | YES |
| [index storage parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-STORAGE-PARAMETERS) | YES | YES | YES | YES |
| [`tablespace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-tablespaces.html) | YES | YES | YES | YES |
| [partial (`WHERE`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html#INDEXES-PARTIAL) | YES | no | [no](https://dbfiddle.uk/6KLYJZno) | YES |
| [multi-column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) | YES | YES | YES | YES |
| [`deferred` validation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html) | no | YES | YES | YES |
| [`nulls not distinct`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#id-1.5.8.8.14.1) | YES | YES | YES | YES* *(emulated by `coalesce()` or requires `not distinct from` operator)* |
| [creating `concurrently`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY) | YES | no | YES | no *(and no equivalent index syntax to enable adding as constraint)* |

In general, the price for the flexibility of an exclusion constraint is [performance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE):

> If all of the specified operators test for equality, this is equivalent to a `UNIQUE` constraint, although an ordinary **unique constraint will be faster**. However, exclusion constraints can specify constraints that are more general than simple equality.

It's also harder to set up for multiple fields because you need to somehow merge them into one, which further complicates the configuration, possibly at even higher performance penalty.

[Demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BRnO7Rbf)

---

Constraint:

```
create table t (
    id bigserial primary key,
    val1 text,
    val2 text,
    unique /*concurrently*/
        nulls not distinct 
       ( val1 
       /*collate unicode 
         text_ops 
         desc nulls last
         with operator(pg_catalog.=)*/) 
        include(val2)
        with(fillfactor=100)
        using index tablespace pg_default
        --where (id%2=1)
        deferrable initially deferred
);
```

Index:

```
create table t2 (
    id bigserial primary key,
    val1 text,
    val2 text
);
create unique index concurrently 
  on t2 (val1 
         collate unicode 
         text_ops 
         desc nulls last
         /*with operator(pg_catalog.=)*/) 
  include(val2)
  nulls not distinct 
  with(fillfactor=100)
  tablespace pg_default
  where id%2=1
  /*deferrable initially deferred*/;
```

Index added as constraint:

```
create unique index concurrently uidx
  on t3 (val1 
         /*collate unicode 
         text_ops 
         desc nulls last
         with operator(pg_catalog.=)*/) 
  include(val2)
  nulls not distinct 
  with(fillfactor=100)
  tablespace pg_default
  /*where id%2=1*/;
alter table t3 
  add constraint ucns 
  unique using index uidx 
  deferrable initially deferred;
```

Exclusion:

```
create table t4 (
    id bigserial primary key,
    val1 text check(val1<>'reserved'),
    val2 text,
    exclude /*concurrently*/
            (coalesce(val1,'reserved') 
             collate unicode 
             text_ops 
             desc nulls last 
             with operator(pg_catalog.=))
        include(val2)
        with(fillfactor=100)
        using index tablespace pg_default
        where (id%2=1)
        deferrable initially deferred
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I read this in the doc:

> ADD table_constraint [ NOT VALID ]
>
> This form adds a new constraint to a table using the same syntax as `CREATE TABLE`, plus the option `NOT VALID`, which is currently only allowed for foreign key constraints. If the constraint is marked `NOT VALID`, the potentially-lengthy initial check to verify that all rows in the table satisfy the constraint is **skipped**. The constraint will still be enforced against **subsequent inserts or updates** (that is, they'll fail unless there is a matching row in the referenced table). But the database *will not* assume that the constraint holds for all rows in the table, until it is validated by using the VALIDATE CONSTRAINT option.

So I think it is what you call "partial uniqueness" by adding a constraint.

And, about how to ensure the uniqueness:

> Adding a unique constraint will automatically create a unique B-tree index on the column or group of columns listed in the constraint. A uniqueness restriction covering only some rows cannot be written as a unique constraint, but it is possible to enforce such a restriction by creating a unique partial index.
>
> Note: The preferred way to add a unique constraint to a table is ALTER TABLE … ADD CONSTRAINT. The use of indexes to enforce unique constraints could be considered an implementation detail that should not be accessed directly. One should, however, be aware that there’s no need to manually create indexes on unique columns; doing so would just duplicate the automatically-created index.

So we should add constraint, which creates an index, to ensure uniqueness.

How I see this problem?

A "constraint" aims to *gramatically* ensure that this column should be unique, it establishes a law, a rule; while "index" is *semantical*, about "how to implement, how to achieve the uniqueness, what does unique means when it comes to implementation". So, the way Postgresql implements it, is very logical: **first, you declare that a column should be unique, then, Postgresql adds the implementation of adding an unique index for you**.

Comment: "So I think it is what you call "partial uniqueness" by adding a constraint." indexes can apply to only a well-defined subset of the records through the `where` clause, so you can define that records are unique IFF they satisfy some criteria. This simply disables the constrains for an undefined set of records which predate the constraint being created. It's completely different, and the latter is significantly *less* useful, though it's convenient for progressive migrations I guess.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT a.phone_number,count(*) FROM public.users a
Group BY phone_number Having count(*)>1;

SELECT a.phone_number,count(*) FROM public.retailers a
Group BY phone_number Having count(*)>1;

select a.phone_number from users a inner join users b
on a.id <> b.id and a.phone_number = b.phone_number order by a.id;


select a.phone_number from retailers a inner join retailers b
on a.id <> b.id and a.phone_number = b.phone_number order by a.id
```

```
DELETE FROM
    users a
        USING users b
WHERE
    a.id > b.id
    AND a.phone_number = b.phone_number;
    
DELETE FROM
    retailers a
        USING retailers b
WHERE
    a.id > b.id
    AND a.phone_number = b.phone_number;
    
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY users_phone_number 
ON users (phone_number);
```

To Verify:

```
insert into users(name,phone_number,created_at,updated_at) select name,phone_number,created_at,updated_at from users
```

Comment: This question is really old, please pay attention to newer ones. I think you wanted to paste this to other post, because it is OT.

Comment: If you think that this answer is related to the given question, please add some explanation to it such that others can learn from it