# Unique constraint vs. unique index?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a difference between:

```
CREATE TABLE p(
    product_no integer,
    name text UNIQUE,
    price numeric
);
```

and:

```
CREATE TABLE p(
        product_no integer,
        name text,
        price numeric
 );
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX customername
  ON p
  USING btree
  (name COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

Will name be unique in both cases? What does it means when an index is unique?

**EDIT**: [Postgres unique constraint vs index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542794/postgres-unique-constraint-vs-index) isn't answering my question. It considers a case with FK. My question has nothing to do with FK's. I just want to know if these two operations are  equivalent **in this example** where no FK is involved.

Comment: They are functionally the same.  A unique constraint creates a unique index.   (I'm trying to think if there is a circumstance where the default collation would *not* be used, but I don't there is any.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgres unique constraint vs index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542794/postgres-unique-constraint-vs-index)

Comment: Maybe different NULL unique treatment? (Just a guess, I don't know postgresql.)

Comment: @klin that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @avi It answers thoroughly and exhaustively to both of your questions. I do not know what question you mean?

Comment: klin, the answer as craig gave is that - there is no diffrance. Please show me how do you get that from the "duplicated" question.

Comment: @avi Craig could not have written that there is no difference, because that would not be true. On the contrary, he mentions three differences. I think you have read inattentively, both his answer and referenced post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there's a small difference. If you define a unique *constraint* it's visible in catalogs like `information_schema`. This is not true of a unique index.

Also, you can create things like partial unique indexes, but you cannot do that on a constraint.

Finally, unique constraints are SQL-standard.

A unique constraint *implies* the creation of a unique index, but not vice versa.

Use a unique constraint unless you have a good reason to create the unique index directly.

Comment: The only reason I've found to use unique indices over unique constraints is the ability to leverage `IF NOT EXISTS`. I gather it's not a great argument, but just sharing my experience for quick development workflows.

Answer (score 4):

From [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html)

> Adding a unique constraint will automatically create a unique btree
>   index on the column or group of columns used in the constraint

So for your simplified example they are equivalent