# Invalid syntax ON CONFLICT when inserting to database

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Trying to insert data to a new empty table with unique constraints.  When I remove the ON CONFLICT statement the code errors out immediately with a violation of the unique constraint in the first insert try even though the table is empty.  When I remove the unique constraints from the table, the data is duplicated when I rerun the code.

I would like the insert to verify if the row exists and do nothing and if it does not exist, to make a new entry.  I'm running postgres 11.3 on Mac OSX.  Any help appreciated.

```
psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cur,
    "insert  into ferc_hots (html,link) values %s",
    values)
on conflict (html,link) do nothing

con.commit()  
print("Records inserted successfully")  
con.close()
```

Comment: `ON CONFLICT` should be within the SQL portion of the code, not part of the Python code.

Comment: not sure how to fix this.  Still getting a syntax error when I move the ) after values to the end of the conflict statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fix should really be simple since you just have the `on conflict` line in the wrong place.

```
psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cur,
    """insert  into ferc_hots (html,link) values %s
       on conflict (html,link) do nothing""", # Moved to inside SQL
    values)

con.commit()  
print("Records inserted successfully")  
con.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That code produces the following error: psycopg2.errors.InvalidColumnReference: "there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification".  Both columns html and link have unique constraints as well.

Comment: Is there a single unique constraint on BOTH - not each - columns?

Comment: there is a unique constraint on each column, not one single constraint for both: Indexes:
    "ferc_hots_html_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (html)
    "ferc_hots_link_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (link)

Comment: That is you problem. In your ON CONFLICT clause you are specifying a single constraint (html, link) as having the conflict - not both individually.

Comment: Would creating a unique index work better than just creating unique constraints for both tables?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542794/postgres-unique-constraint-vs-index .

Comment: OK so i fixed the ON CONFLICT issue.  I had 3 items in the "values" list and did not have these items in the insert code.  I also defined the primary key value to include both columns (html,link) in the postgres table.  All working now.  Thanks!

Comment: How to do this in Odoo?