# jooq - problem recognizing postgres UNIQUE constraint

Tags: postgresql, jooq

Am attempting :

```
context.insertInto(table(ERROR_TABLE))
  .set(valuesMap)
  .onConflictOnConstraint(constraint(name("push_def_rec_error_idx"))
  .doUpdate()
  .set(field(name(fieldname)), value)
  .execute();
```

Am getting an error telling me:

> ERROR: constraint "push_def_rec_error_idx" for table "push_error" does not exist

Table definition (via `\d+ table_name`):

```
...

Indexes:
    "push_record_error_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (push_record_error_id)
    "push_def_rec_error_idx" UNIQUE, btree (push_definition_id, rec_id)
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is for **SQLDialect.POSTGRES_10**

Comment: Is that really a constraint or an "just" a unique index?

Comment: In my (albeit ignorant) mind they are one and the same. Perhaps not to jooq?

Comment: Also, not to PostgreSQL. `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` and `ALTER TABLE .. ADD CONSTRAINT` are not the same thing. Does the statement produced by jOOQ work if you run it in PostgreSQL directly?

Answer (score 1):

The way you named your indexes, I'm assuming you don't have a constraint on those columns, but a `UNIQUE INDEX`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE T (a INT PRIMARY KEY, b INT, c INT);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX u ON t(b);

INSERT INTO T (a, b, c)
VALUES (1, 2, 3)
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT u
DO UPDATE SET c = 4
RETURNING *;
```

The above produces:

```
[42704]: ERROR: constraint "u" for table "t" does not exist
```

However, turn the index into a constraint:

```sql
DROP INDEX u;
ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT u UNIQUE (b);
```

And the `INSERT` statement now works.

[See an explanation here about the difference between unique constraints and unique indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23542794/521799). This is not really related to jOOQ