# How to add unique constraint over a time range?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table slot which has a start_time and end_time. I want no other slot to be created having the same start and end time. A unique constraint as shown in the schema below

```
CREATE TABLE slot(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
start_time TIMETZ NOT NULL,
end_time TIMETZ NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT slot_start_end_unique UNIQUE (start_time,end_time)  
);
```

can be easily bypassed by picking up one minute + or - time. I want to add a constraint so that no equivalent time slot can be created or a subset time slot cannot be created.
I am thinking of using `check` to prevent any practically same slot from being created.
Can anyone please point towards the right direction?

Comment: `create table slot(id serial primary key, timeslot tstzrange, exclude using gist (timeslot with &&));` found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74220308/5298879). [Online demo of this](https://dbfiddle.uk/bXBwFnEX)

Comment: @Zegarek this comment should be an answer (the correct one)

Comment: @pablete I'm not sure OP will be easily swayed nearly 4 years later but [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78142485/5298879).

Comment: @Zegarek a good info is a good info :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of using a *check constraint* as unique enforcement is can probable be made to work but there could be issues and should probably be avoided. Your requirement necessitates comparing with other rows in the table but

> PostgreSQL does not support CHECK constraints that reference table
> data other than the new or updated row  being checked. ...

It goes on to indicate a custom trigger is best employed. So, that is the approach here.  See  [Section 5.4.1. Check Constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS).  

Beyond that you have a couple issues: First off the data type TIME WITH TIMEZONE (TIMETZ) is a poor choice for data type and is somewhat misleading as *it not actually used as indicated* as the.  As [Section 8.5.3. Time Zones](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) puts it:

> Although the date type cannot have an associated time zone, the time
> type can. Time zones in the real world have little meaning unless
> associated with a date as well as a time, ... **PostgreSQL assumes
> your local time zone for any type containing only date or time.**
> (emphases mine)

Secondly, by using time only you may have problems specifying some ranges. How, for example, do you code the range from 22:00 to 06:00 or 23:45 to 00:15. But now back to the  process.  
The following trigger assumes data type TIME rather than TIMETZ and adjusts for the over midnight issue by assuming 'the next day' whenever start_time is greater than end_time.

```
create or replace                                                                                                 
function  is_valid_irange()                                                             
   returns trigger                                                                                               
   language plpgsql                                                                                        
   strict  
as $$ 
declare 
    k_existing_message constant text = 
        'Range Requested (%s,%s). Overlaps existing range (%s,%s).';
       
    l_existing_range  tsrange;
    l_parm_range      tsrange;
   
begin 
    with p_times(new_start_time, new_end_time) as                                                                         
         ( values ('1970-01-01'::timestamp + new.start_time                                                        
                  ,'1970-01-01'::timestamp + new.end_time                                                          
                  )                                                                                               
         )                                                                                                                                                                                          
    select tsrange(new_start_time,end_time,'[)')
      into l_parm_range 
      from (select new_start_time                                                                               
                 , case when new_start_time>new_end_time                                                            
                        then new_end_time + interval '1 day'                                                     
                        else new_end_time                                                                        
                    end end_time                                                                             
              from p_times                                                                                  
           ) pr;                                                                                             
                                                                                                      
    with db_range (id, existing_range) as 
         ( select id, tsrange(start_time, end_time, '[)')                                                                                                      
            from ( select id, '1970-01-01'::timestamp + start_time  start_time                                                
                        , case  when start_time>end_time                                                        
                                then '1970-01-02'::timestamp + end_time                                         
                                else '1970-01-01'::timestamp + end_time                                         
                            end end_time                                                                                   
                     from irange                                                                                
                 ) dr
         )
   select d.existing_range
     into l_existing_range 
     from db_range    d
    where l_parm_range && existing_range
      and d.id != new.id
     limit 1;

   if l_existing_range is not null
   then 
       raise exception 'Invalid Range Requested:' 
       using detail= format( k_existing_message 
                           , lower(l_parm_range)
                           , upper(l_parm_range)
                           , lower(l_existing_range)::time
                           , upper(l_existing_range)::time
                           ); 
    end if;
 
  return new; 
end ;
$$;
```

**How it works:**  
Postgres provides a set of built in data [range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) and a set of [range operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE) functions.
The trigger coheres the start and end times,both new row and existing table rows, into timestamps with a fixed date ( the beginning of time 1970-01-01 according to unix).
Then employs the Overlaps (&&) operator. If any overlaps are found the trigger raises and exception. Instead of an exception it could *return null* to suppress
the insert or update but otherwise continue processing. For that it needs to become a BEFORE trigger. It is currently an AFTER trigger.  

For full example see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c080356226c519161b4b378a3f8c9b49). Do not worry about the date, pick any you want, just used a a generator for calculating times and to provide a common base for testing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I am going through it. I am not relying entirely on timetz I am saving tz-timezone in string format in some other table.

Answer (score 1):

1. PostgreSQL has built-in [range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) since 2012 [version 9.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/9.2.0/). You don't need to hold bounds separately and compare to them individually.
2. Whenever you're looking for a sort-of-`unique` constraint, but using non-standard equality, you're actually looking for an [*exclusion constraint*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE) - they were added in [v9.0](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/9.0.0/) in 2010. [Here's some more on different ways to do `unique`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542794/postgres-unique-constraint-vs-index/77476513#77476513) [Demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/bXBwFnEX)

```sql
create table slot(
    id int generated by default as identity primary key, 
    timeslot tstzrange, 
    exclude using gist (timeslot with &&));
```

3. There's no [`time`- or `timetz`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-TABLE)-based range type out of the box, but if you really want time of day (without date), it's very easy to set it up. And it'll immediately work with all relevant [functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html), *automagically*: [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/SoHnZJxo)

```sql
create type ttzrange as range(subtype=timetz);

create table slot(
    id int generated by default as identity primary key, 
    timeslot ttzrange, 
    exclude using gist (timeslot with &&));
```

4. As a bonus, a corresponding multirange is automatically created with your custom range type - you can use those to have ranges with breaks: [demo3](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ws8ADb5l)

```sql
--note that you don't need to create ttzmultirange separately
--it got automatically added when you created the base ttzrange type
create table multislot(
    id int generated by default as identity primary key, 
    timeslot ttzmultirange, 
    exclude using gist (timeslot with &&));
```

Answer (score -1):

Create the table as normal then before you INSERT data into the table perform a SELECT query to search whether or not the time you are looking to insert already exists. For example you want to enter start 1pm and end 2pm as such:

DECLARE @start_value INT = 1
@end_value INT = 2;

Select COUNT(ID) as UseCheck FROM slot WHERE start_time = @start_value or end_time = @end_value

Then apply logic to say; IF UseCheck > 0 Then do stuff