# Adding a unique index or constraint that checks other rows - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table containing `redemptions`, each of which has a `user_id`. I'm trying to prevent a user from performing more than one redemption in 24 hours.

The SQL I've tried so far is:

```
ALTER TABLE "redemptions"
ADD CONSTRAINT "one_redemption_per_user_per_twenty_four_hours"
CHECK (
  NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT u from users WHERE u.inserted_at >= now() + INTERVAL '24 hours'
    AND user_id = u.user_id;
  )
)
```

Which results in `** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42601 (syntax_error) syntax error at or near ";"`

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do? If not, how can I fix the above?

Thanks,
Mark

EDIT: Redemption table structure as requested:

```
|  id  |  user_id  | voucher_id  |  inserted_at  | updated_at
```

Comment: Could you please show which columns and data are in the two tables?

Comment: Remove the ; from your query inside the check constraint

Comment: A check constraint reports a syntax error due to the semicolon but once you fix that, it'll tell you a subquery isn't allowed there at all: `ERROR:  cannot use subquery in check constraint`. `CHECK` and `EXCLUDE` constraints are limited to [`IMMUTABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html) functions, current time-returning functions don't meet the criteria by nature and it's not viable to build a purposefully misclassified wrapper around them. I think a validation trigger will be an easier way to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks @Zegarek, I'll take a look at validation triggers

Comment: [Similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63905014/5298879) and also see [notes in the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) on why CHECK isn't advised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createtable.html)

> Currently, CHECK expressions cannot contain subqueries nor refer to
> variables other than columns of the current row (see Section 5.4.1).
> The system column tableoid may be referenced, but not any other system
> column.

Even it this was supported, the performance would be horrible.

[There is a better way to do it.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT)

Make sure [GiST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gist-intro.html) indexes work: `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist;`

```
create table redemption(
 id bigserial, 
 user_id bigint,
 voucher_id bigint,
 validity tstzrange default (tstzrange(now(),now()+'24 hours'::interval), 
 EXCLUDE USING GIST (user_id WITH =, validity WITH &&)
);
```

The constraint ensures that a `user_id`, at a given point in time, has only one active voucher.

Example:

Step 1: user 1 used voucher 2 just now. Default validity is 24 hours.

```sql
    INSERT INTO redemption(user_id,voucher_id) 
    VALUES (1,2);
```

Step 2: user 1 tries to use another voucher (3) in 12 hours:

```sql
    INSERT INTO redemption(user_id,voucher_id,validity)
    VALUES
    (1,3,tstzrange(now()+'12 hours'::interval,now()+'36 hours'::interval));
```

PostgreSQL replies with:

```
ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "redemption_user_id_validity_excl"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id, validity)=(1, ["2022-10-28 00:01:56.422834+02","2022-10-29 00:01:56.422834+02")) conflicts with existing key (user_id, validity)=(1, ["2022-10-27 12:00:45.750125+02","2022-10-28 12:00:45.750125+02")).
```

PostgreSQL automatically check that is no overlap in the validity range for a given user.

The performance is guaranteed by the fact that the [EXCLUDE constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION) automatically creates an appropriate index. Here's the table as reported by psql:

```
\d+ redemption
                                                   Table "public.redemption"
   Column   |   Type    | Collation | Nullable |                 Default                    | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
------------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id         | bigint    |           | not null | nextval('redemption_id_seq'::regclass)     | plain    |              | 
 user_id    | bigint    |           |          |                                            | plain    |              | 
 voucher_id | bigint    |           |          |                                            | plain    |              | 
 validity   | tstzrange |           |          | tstzrange(now(),now()+'24 hours'::interval | extended |              | 
Indexes:
    "redemption_user_id_validity_excl" EXCLUDE USING gist (user_id WITH =, validity WITH &&)
Access method: heap
```

Additionally, it probably makes sense to add another constraint about a voucher being [unique](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS), to avoid the case where a voucher is used multiple times.

Thus:

```
create table redemption(
 id bigserial, 
 user_id bigint,
 voucher_id bigint UNIQUE,
 validity tstzrange default (tstzrange(now(),now()+'24 hours'::interval), 
 EXCLUDE USING GIST (user_id WITH =, validity WITH &&)
);
```

Comment: I looked into `EXCLUDE` constraints but couldn't figure out a way to apply them with `timestamp` without the need for a subquery or at least the EXCLUDED/NEW/OLD type of context. `tstzrange` with `&&` is brilliant. I'd only [add](https://dbfiddle.uk/8dsL7dml) `default now()` and `default (tstzrange(now(),now()+'1 day'::interval)` to save some time on specifying what's likely the most common insert value.

Comment: I just found this is almost the exact advice [from the manual, in the section about range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT). Might be worth adding this link.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this out, implementing now