# Unique together constraint using peewee

Tags: python, orm, peewee

Is it way to apply unique by two columns constraint to model using peewee. There are raw way (using `SQL()`) but I'm finding another.

### Updated:

I'm using postgres so I tried to do like @booshong says below then in raw SQL I gave the following (for simplicity transaction related `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` omitted and output was intended):

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "foo" (
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "field_1" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "field_2" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "foo_field_1_field_2" 
    ON "foo" ("field_1", "field_2");

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "foo2" (
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "field_1" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "field_2" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    UNIQUE (field_1, field_2));
```

And as we can see it's different things as I say earlier.

Comment: did you read the [documentation](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#multi-column-indexes)?

Comment: @booshong , of course. Unless I didn't write here. In peewee you can only create multi index using pretty python syntax. For unique together there aren't something beautiful. So I was forced to use `constraints = [SQL('UNIQUE (field_1, field_2)']`in meta class.

Comment: maybe i'm not understanding the question. Why can't you just do `indexes = ((('field_1', 'field_2'), True),)` (under `class Meta:`)?

Comment: Index and constraint are two different things. Do not сonfuse it.

Comment: what database are you using? Generally (e.g. MySQL), these are the same thing under the hood. The unique constraint needs the index to function. Try both methods and look at the schema definition. On MySQL they will be the same.

Comment: I'm using postgres. See what attached in question under "updated"

Comment: I think there isn't so way yet. Anyway thank you, @booshong, for attention

Comment: From what I understand creating a constraint will create an index anyways. I'd suggest just using the Meta.indexes, but if you absolutely insist, you can just specify it in the `constraints=`.

Comment: Regarding your edit: yes the SQL commands used by the two approaches are different, but if you can't find any difference between the resulting schema definitions (try `\d <table>` on those two tables and compare) then they are effectively the same. I don't have a lot of experience with postgres, so maybe there is a difference there, though based on these ([#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542794/postgres-unique-constraint-vs-index), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542794/postgres-unique-constraint-vs-index)) questions, it seems like it's small. Interesting discussion

Comment: You're right. Difference between unique index and unique constraint is very small. Difference is in fact that index have b-tree and rdbs forced to keep it updated. I think it unlikely can be performance issue, but fact is fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
class Foo(BaseModel):
    field_1 = CharField()
    field_2 = CharField()

    class Meta:
        indexes = (
            (('field_1', 'field_2'), True),
        )


class Foo2(BaseModel):
    field_1 = CharField()
    field_2 = CharField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [SQL('UNIQUE (field_1, field_2)')]


Foo.create_table()
Foo2.create_table()
```

```sql
-- MySQL v8

show create table foo;
>> CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field_1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `field_2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `foo_field_1_field_2` (`field_1`,`field_2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci


show create table foo2;
>> CREATE TABLE `foo2` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field_1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `field_2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `field_1` (`field_1`,`field_2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

The two tables are equivalent.