# SQLAlchemy create unique constraint with the hash value of multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgresql-14

I want to create a `UniqueConstraint` using a hash of multiple columns.
Postgresql 15 provides the hash function `hash_record_extended`, but I couldn't figure out the syntax.

```
__table_args__ = (
    UniqueConstraint(
        func.hash_record_extended(
            (
                "col1",
                "col2",
                "col3",
            ),
            0, 
        ),
    ),
)
```

The above gives the error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't add unnamed column to column collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: As per [this sqlalchemy discussion](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4434) functions in `UniqueConstraint` is not supported. I am leaving a solution that uses unique index instead if that helps. You could check [Postgres unique constraint vs index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542794/postgres-unique-constraint-vs-index) for some explanation.

I am not really sure if `hash_record_extended` is a public facing api as I can not seem to find in the docs (will edit this appropriately if anyone can find a source). That being said, you can create a normal index and make it unique like so. This will raise `IntegrityError` if you attempt to insert non unique values.

```py
Index(
    "some_name",
    func.hash_record_extended(func.row(col1, col2, col3), 0),
    unique=True,
)
```

This generates the following sql

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX some_name ON some_table (
  hash_record_extended(
    row(col1, col2, col3), 
    0
  )
)
```

Complete copy-pasteable code using SQLAlchemy 2

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, func, Index
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, DeclarativeBase, mapped_column

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class SomeTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "some_table"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    col1: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    col2: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    col3: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    __table_args__ = (
        Index(
            "some_name",
            func.hash_record_extended(func.row(col1, col2, col3), 0),
            unique=True,
        ),
    )

connection_string = "postgresql+psycopg://"
engine = create_engine(connection_string, echo=True)
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Comment: `hash_record_extended` available only from postgresql 14

Comment: @shmnff did not know that, but can you help me understand why this returns no result? https://www.postgresql.org/search/?q=hash_record_extended I would assume it would search for anything irrespective of the version

Comment: [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/299098/why-doesnt-my-unique-constraint-trigger) is some explanation