# What is the difference between unique index and constaraint unique in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

The first way to guarantee unique of many fields in to use constraint

```
create table t
(
    id bigserial primary key,
    val1 integer,
    val2 integer,
    unique (val1, val2)
);
```

On the other hand, we can use unique index

```
create table t
(
    id bigserial primary key,
    val1 integer,
    val2 integer
);

create unique index unique_val1_val2
on t (val1, val2);
```

is there any difference here? mb they will work differently with null values?

I have not noticed any difference while testing

Comment: Does [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/147) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS):

> Adding a unique constraint will automatically create a unique B-tree
> index on the column or group of columns listed in the constraint. A
> uniqueness restriction covering only some rows cannot be written as a
> unique constraint, but it is possible to enforce such a restriction by
> creating a unique partial index.

The handling of NULLs depends on you, NULLS NOT DISTINCT or NULLS DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is none*. They [enforce uniqueness](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index-unique-checks.html) exactly the same way and they offer *almost* the exact same level of control over the index: you're right that one of the differences is related to null handling. [Demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/DS-p35ST)

```sql
create table t
(
    id bigserial primary key,
    val1 integer,
    val2 integer,
    unique nulls not distinct (val1 /*desc nulls last*/) 
        include(val2)
        with(fillfactor=100)
        using index tablespace pg_default
        --where id%2=1
        deferrable initially deferred
);
```

The parts that are commented out above cannot be defined within [`constraint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-UNIQUE) syntax but they are allowed by the equivalent [`index`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html) syntax, and vice versa: indexes don't accept [`deferrability`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-DEFERRABLE) behaviour spec.

```sql
create table t2
(
    id bigserial primary key,
    val1 integer,
    val2 integer
);
create unique index on t2 (val1 desc nulls last) 
  include(val2)
  nulls not distinct 
  with(fillfactor=100)
  tablespace pg_default
  where id%2=1
  /*deferrable initially deferred*/;
```

---

There's also a third option to enforce uniqueness, an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE):

```
create table t3
(
    id bigserial primary key,
    val1 integer,
    val2 integer,
    exclude (coalesce(val1,-1) desc nulls last with =)
        include(val2)
        with(fillfactor=100)
        using index tablespace pg_default
        where (id%2=1)
        deferrable initially deferred
);
```

And this time around, while it does also use an index under the hood, it does not work the same:

> If all of the specified operators test for equality, this is equivalent to a `UNIQUE` constraint, although an ordinary **unique constraint will be faster**. However, exclusion constraints can specify constraints that are more general than simple equality.

It's also harder to set up for multiple fields because you need to somehow merge them into one (array, json, range etc.).

Comment: That `coalesce()` is a simple trick to substitute missing `nulls not distinct` clause at the expense of overlap between `null` and `-1`. The correct but trickier method is to declare a commutative [`operator`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createoperator.html) using `is not distinct from` instead of `=`, put it in a [`class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createopclass.html) and add to a [`family`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alteropfamily.html) usable by [`btree`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-support-funcs.html).

Comment: Since the thread's being closed as duplicate, I [moved this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77476513/5298879) accordingly.