# NestJS / Sequelize duplicate key value violates unique constraint error

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sequelize.js, nestjs

I have faced this issue with my database:

```
2023-12-15 12:31:31.913 UTC [95] ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_roles_company_user_id_key"
```

Generally speaking, I have the database that can be described using the following concept: there are different companies, company users belong to the companies, companies (their users) can created different custom roles and these roles can be assigned to the different company users.

Here is the part of this database description generated by DataGrip (I will skip some unimportant fields of tables):

[image]

And here is the models I have written in order to generated this database with these foreign keys:

Table `users_roles`:

```
@Table({ tableName: 'users_roles' })
export class UserRole extends Model<UserRole> {
  @PrimaryKey
  @Default(DataType.UUIDV4)
  @Column(DataType.UUID)
  id: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => CompanyUser)
  @Column({ type: DataType.UUID, allowNull: false, field: 'company_user_id', unique: false })
  companyUserId: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => Company)
  @Column({ type: DataType.UUID, allowNull: false, field: 'company_id', unique: false })
  companyId: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => Role)
  @Column({ type: DataType.UUID, allowNull: false, field: 'role_id', unique: false })
  roleId: string;
}
```

Table `companies`:

```
@Table({ tableName: 'companies' })
export class Company extends Model<Company, CompanyCreationAttributes> {
  @PrimaryKey
  @Default(DataType.UUIDV4)
  @Column(DataType.UUID)
  id: string;

  @BelongsTo(() => User)
  user: User;

  @HasMany(() => CompanyUser)
  companyUsers: Array<CompanyUser>;

  @BelongsToMany(() => Role, () => UserRole)
  roles: Array<Role>;
}
```

Table `roles`:

```
@Table({ tableName: 'roles' })
export class Role extends Model<Role> {
  @PrimaryKey
  @Default(DataType.UUIDV4)
  @Column(DataType.UUID)
  id: string;

  @BelongsToMany(() => CompanyUser, () => UserRole)
  companyUsers: Array<CompanyUser>;

  @BelongsToMany(() => Company, () => UserRole)
  companies: Array<Company>;
}
```

Table `company_user`:

```
@Table({ tableName: 'company_users' })
export class CompanyUser extends Model<
  CompanyUser,
  CompanyUserCreationAttributes
> {
  @PrimaryKey
  @Default(DataType.UUIDV4)
  @Column(DataType.UUID)
  id: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @Column({ type: DataType.UUID, allowNull: false, field: 'user_id' })
  userId: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => Company)
  @Column({ type: DataType.UUID, allowNull: false, field: 'company_id' })
  companyId: string;

  @BelongsTo(() => Company)
  company: Company;

  @BelongsToMany(() => Role, () => UserRole)
  roles: Array<Role>;
}
```

Honestly, probably I am just blind and cannot spot the error, because for some reason, in the `users_roles` I can have 2 records with the same `company_id`, but not `company_user_id`, or maybe I have messed up somewhere with database foreign keys...

Thanks everyone in advance for the help! I relly appreciate this!

Edited:

Indexes/constraints of the table:

```
SELECT c2.relname, i.indisprimary, i.indisunique, i.indisclustered, i.indisvalid, pg_catalog.pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid, 0, true),
  pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(con.oid, true), contype, condeferrable, condeferred, i.indisreplident, c2.reltablespace
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c, pg_catalog.pg_class c2, pg_catalog.pg_index i
  LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_constraint con ON (conrelid = i.indrelid AND conindid = i.indexrelid AND contype IN ('p','u','x'))
WHERE c.oid = 'users_roles'::regclass::oid AND c.oid = i.indrelid AND i.indexrelid = c2.oid
ORDER BY i.indisprimary DESC, c2.relname;
```

| relname | indisprimary | indisunique | indisclustered | indisvalid | pg_get_indexdef | pg_get_constraintdef | contype | condeferrable | condeferred | indisreplident | reltablespace |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| users_roles_pkey | true | true | false | true | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_roles_pkey ON users_roles USING btree (id) | PRIMARY KEY (id) | p | false | false | false | 0 |
| users_roles_company_id_role_id_key | false | true | false | true | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_roles_company_id_role_id_key ON users_roles USING btree (company_id, role_id) | UNIQUE (company_id, role_id) | u | false | false | false | 0 |
| users_roles_company_user_id_key | false | true | false | true | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_roles_company_user_id_key ON users_roles USING btree (company_user_id) | UNIQUE (company_user_id) | u | false | false | false | 0 |

Comment: And what does the user_roles.companyUserId field represent? The creator user or the assigned user?

Comment: @SalmanA user_roles.companyUserId field represents the id of the user in the company_users table.

Comment: @SalmanA `show create table users_roles` does not work, I assume this is because of PostgreSQL syntax, since I have this DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [icons on the DataGrip diagram](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/creating-diagrams.html#icons) indicate there's an index on all 3 foreign key columns of `users_roles`.

One of those must be the unique index behind your unexpected and unwanted `unique constraint "users_roles_company_user_id_key"` (every [unique constraint builds and uses a unique index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77476513/5298879) as of PostgreSQL 16) and it's a result of [default `@BelongsToMany()` behaviour](https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/associations/belongs-to-many/#through-pair-unique-constraint):

> The BelongsToMany association creates a unique key on the foreign keys of the through model.

You can disable it by overriding `unique`:

```js
@BelongsToMany(() => Role,{through:{model: 'UserRole',
                                    unique: false, //----here
                                   },
                          }
              )
```

Although it's not the case here, it's also possible to get this error if you define your foreign key column as unique directly:

```js
@Table({ tableName: 'users_roles' })
export class UserRole extends Model<UserRole> {
  //...
  @ForeignKey(() => CompanyUser)
  @Column({ type: DataType.UUID, 
            allowNull: false, 
            field: 'company_user_id', 
            unique: false //-----------here
          })
  companyUserId: string;
  //...
}
```

It's also possible to set up an [`@Index`](https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/models/indexes/) in your models, or [define and sync it separately](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/indexes/) or even completely elsewhere, [directly on db](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html) - if you do that setting `unique: true`, you'll also get this error. The index on its own is definitely helpful, it just shouldn't be set up as unique unless clearly necessary; you need to find it and make it a regular, non-unique index.

In a failed migration scenario when you attempted to change the model, something went wrong and you didn't fully resolve the problem, you can also have a "stray" unique index/constraint from before the change - in that case your CI/CD logs should tell you the details.

You can [check your constraints/indexes with DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/indexes.html) - there, it might be enough to untick the *unique* checkbox. In [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) `\d users_roles` will list those, which is equivalent to running the queries listed below (add the schema name before `users_roles`). You should probably see `users_roles_company_user_id_key` defined as `unique` - as a temporary workaround, you could copy that definition, [`drop index`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropindex.html) and run that definition again, just removing the `unique` part, before attempting to populate the tables.

Indexes/constraints on the table:

```sql
SELECT c2.relname, i.indisprimary, i.indisunique, i.indisclustered, i.indisvalid, pg_catalog.pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid, 0, true),
  pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(con.oid, true), contype, condeferrable, condeferred, i.indisreplident, c2.reltablespace
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c, pg_catalog.pg_class c2, pg_catalog.pg_index i
  LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_constraint con ON (conrelid = i.indrelid AND conindid = i.indexrelid AND contype IN ('p','u','x'))
WHERE c.oid = 'users_roles'::regclass::oid AND c.oid = i.indrelid AND i.indexrelid = c2.oid
ORDER BY i.indisprimary DESC, c2.relname;
```

Foreign keys pointing from this table

```
SELECT true as sametable, conname,
  pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(r.oid, true) as condef,
  conrelid::pg_catalog.regclass AS ontable
FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint r
WHERE r.conrelid = 'users_roles'::regclass::oid AND r.contype = 'f'
     AND conparentid = 0
ORDER BY conname
```

Foreign keys pointing at this table

```sql
SELECT conname, conrelid::pg_catalog.regclass AS ontable,
       pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(oid, true) AS condef
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint c
 WHERE confrelid IN (SELECT pg_catalog.pg_partition_ancestors('users_roles'::regclass)
                     UNION ALL VALUES ('users_roles'::regclass))
       AND contype = 'f' AND conparentid = 0
ORDER BY conname;
```

Comment: I have my database in docker containers, so I rerun it infinite amount of times and it did not help. Therefore, I assume, that the error is on the level of the code itself.

Comment: Gotcha, well, you know, I guess I have provided all parts of code that are interconnected in the database, but you were right in terms of needless set up indexes since I was able to find them (at least I hope so), anyway, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I have executed the first query you have and here is what I have got (check the edited question). If I understand correcrly, this column `indisunique` tells us that this is unique, even tho in the code, as you have seen, I explicitly make them `unique: false`.

Comment: Also, I would like to add that I don't use `@Index` anywhere in my code.

Comment: I swear, you won't be able to find any `@Index` in my code or even `unique: true`. And this is what is confusing me. Generally speaking, right now what I am trying to achive is to make it `unique: false`. @Zegarek

Comment: Nothing that contains `index` at all. In terms of any solutions, could you please provide more informaion in your answer on what I need to do? I will be honest, I am not really that advanced in the databases and DB management, espesially when it comes to indexes etc.

Comment: let me then share the whole code of the project, so you may spot something that I can't do

Comment: Gotcha, thank you so much once again! You are my lifesaver!

Comment: @dokichan It looks like that was it: the unique constraint likely comes from `@BelongsTo` `@BelongsToMany` and `@HasMany`. You can [disable that constraint by changing the through table config](https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/associations/belongs-to-many/#through-pair-unique-constraint). I've taken down previous comments but have them saved to properly summarize the process in the answer later. Let me know how this tinkering with the through table plays out and I'll edit that in

Comment: @Zegerek Got you, thank you so much once again! Gonna play around with this tomorrow and ping you in case if I am able to solve this issue.