# Postgres Unique Constraint Grows with null values

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I'm using postgres 14 and I realised that a Unique Constraint size seems to grow even when null values are being inserted.

```sql
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE column;
```

Given that Unique Constraints generally don't really consider null as unique, this is rather surprising.

We can achieve the same uniqueness constraint using less disk space by using a partial index as such below.

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON "table" ("column") WHERE "column" IS NOT NULL;
```

Unfortunately it's not as simple as changing unique constraints to use partial unique indexes. You lose capabilities such as `ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT` and deferred checking. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60707035/4052597)

Is there another way to apply the unique constraint whilst not having null values add up to the disk space?

Comment: Hmmm...are you certain that _other_, non null data, is not also being inserted at the same time?

Comment: Yes I have a table with multiple unique constraints on multiple columns and each constraint is the same size despite some columns having 99% null data and others having 1% null data.

Comment: This is interesting. Formally (null=null) is false, respectively, each null value is unique.

Answer (score 2):

NULL values are indexed just like all other data. The only way to avoid that is a partial unique index.

You are correct that the check from a partial index cannot be deferred, but it can be used with `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`. Just add the appropriate `WHERE` condition to the conflict target.

Comment: oh interesting, i guess the insert on conflict isnt an issue when replacing with a partial unique index exlcuding nulls then? So the only issue is partial index not being deferrable?