# Postgresql do I have to create an index or is that already an index?

Tags: postgresql

I am new and want to know:

is this already an index ?

```
ALTER TABLE workers_times ADD CONSTRAINT no_overlap_times EXCLUDE USING gist (user_id WITH =, available WITH &&)
```

I dont want to overlap the times but I add a constraint with gist. So is this now an index or should I still create an index like this

```
CREATE INDEX I_WORKERS_TIMES ON workers_times(user_id, available);
```

or is the index above not necessarry ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an index in the sense that it automatically creates one. [Constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html) don't strictly have to involve an index at all, [this one does](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html):

> Exclusion constraints are implemented using an index, so each specified operator must be associated with an appropriate operator class (see Section 11.10) for the index access method `index_method`.

You were right to suspect it would because `unique` (thus also `primary key`) automatically creates and is enforced by an index, and creating a unique constraint is sometimes exchanged for only creating a unique index, since they end up delivering the same functionality:

> Adding a unique constraint will automatically create a unique B-tree index on the column or group of columns listed in the constraint.

Keep in mind all these are just implementation details and however unlikely, they could change in the future

---

In `psql` you can run [`\d+ workers_times`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-D) meta-command to see all constraints *and* indexes on the table, whether they were created separately or as a part of a constraint - this exclusion constraint is listed as an index: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/PIu5qr48)

```sql
create table workers_times(
    user_id uuid,
    available tstzrange);

create extension btree_gist;

ALTER TABLE workers_times 
  ADD CONSTRAINT no_overlap_times 
  EXCLUDE USING gist (user_id WITH =, available WITH &&);
```

```sql
\d+ workers_times
                                         Table "public.workers_times"
  Column   |   Type    | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Compression | Stats target | Description
-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 user_id   | uuid      |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 available | tstzrange |           |          |         | extended |             |              |
Indexes:
    "no_overlap_times" EXCLUDE USING gist (user_id WITH =, available WITH &&)
Access method: heap
```

---

[Here's a table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77476513/5298879) showing the differences between what index, constraint, index as constraint and an exclusion constraint can do:

| control over | index | constraint | index as constraint | exclusion constraint |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [collation, direction, `null` order](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#id-1.9.3.69.6) | YES | no | [no](https://dbfiddle.uk/7iqUNzfV) | YES |
| [custom equality](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createoperator.html) | no | no | no | YES |
| [`include`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#id-1.9.3.69.6) payload column | YES | YES | YES | YES |
| [index storage parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-STORAGE-PARAMETERS) | YES | YES | YES | YES |
| [`tablespace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-tablespaces.html) | YES | YES | YES | YES |
| [partial (`WHERE`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html#INDEXES-PARTIAL) | YES | no | [no](https://dbfiddle.uk/6KLYJZno) | YES |
| [multi-column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) | YES | YES | YES | YES |
| [`deferred` validation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html) | no | YES | YES | YES |
| [`nulls not distinct`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#id-1.5.8.8.14.1) | YES | YES | YES | YES* *(emulated by `coalesce()` or requires `not distinct from` operator)* |
| [creating `concurrently`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY) | YES | no | YES | no *(and no equivalent index syntax to enable adding as constraint)* |

Comment: Funny how I did a 180 turn here: I even reproduced this and pasted the output of psql telling me: "yup, it made an index", while insisting this won't create an index.