# Simulate a primary key for a nullable column

Tags: postgresql, constraints, primary-key

I handle members' roles in a table with this structure:

- **id**: id of the row
- **id_member**: integer, foreign key is 'id' column in 'members' table
- **id_role**: integer, foreign key is 'id' column in 'roles' table
- **date_start**: timestamp when this user gets the role
- **date_end**: timestamp when this user loses the role

When I add a role, the `date_start` is set with `current_timestamp`, and `date_end` is null.
When I remove a role, the `date_end` is set with `current_timestamp`.

I don't want a user to have several roles at the same time, so initially I thought about setting a triple primary key: `id_member`, `id_role` and `date_end`, but it appears I can't put a nullable column as primary key.

How could I change the structure of the table so that I can prevent a user having 2 active roles? I thought about adding a `active` column but not only would it overcharge the structure, but also I won't be able to save 2 historical roles (if a user was ROLE3 during 4 different periods, for example).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exclusion constraint with a tstzrange column:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT

Comment: I see the documentation, but how could I alter my table? I don't see how I can say "I don't want to have 2 same triplets `id_member`, `id_role` and `date_ned` === NULL

Comment: What about using an unique index instead of the primary key? you could have these columns as your unique index.

Comment: After verification, it doesn't do the trick. I can still add the same triplets.

Comment: But you led me to a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449207/postgres-unique-constraint-not-enforcing-uniqueness/23449309
Thanks. You can add your answer so that I can vote for it if you want.

Comment: Rather that defaulting the end_date to null set the default to `'infinity'::date`2. As a benefit when determining active dated the `between date_start and date_end` works, and satisfactory for PK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want a user to have several roles at the same time

#### Partial `UNIQUE` index

So, each member can only have a single active role (`date_end IS NULL`).
A partial `UNIQUE` index will enforce that:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tbl_member_active_role_uni ON tbl (id_member)
WHERE date_end IS NULL;  -- active role
```

See:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns/8289253#8289253)
- [PostgreSQL multi-column unique constraint and NULL values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9760/3684)

#### `EXCLUDE`

The above still allows to add historic entries that overlap. To disallow that, too, use an [exclusion constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION). You'll need the additional module [`btree_gist`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/btree-gist.html) for your integer column. See:

- [PostgreSQL EXCLUDE USING error: Data type integer has no default operator class](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/37373/3684)

Then:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSTRAINT tbl_member_no_overlapping_role
EXCLUDE USING gist (id_member with =, tsrange(date_start, date_end) WITH &&);
```

`NULL` values for `date_end` happen to work perfectly. In a range types, `NULL` as upper bound signifies "unbounded".
See:

- [How to ensure entries with non-overlapping time ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61716095/how-to-ensure-entries-with-non-overlapping-time-ranges/61779939#61779939)